# start/stop loading when Ajax.BeginForm post method Send/Complete

Tags: jquery, post, ajax.beginform

I am doing ajax call with Ajax.BeginForm in MVC2 like this:

```
using (Ajax.BeginForm("methoname", "controller", new AjaxOptions
{
   HttpMethod = "Post",
   OnSuccess = "OnSuccessUserSave",
   UpdateTargetId = "PopupBody"

}))
```

Now, i want to Show loading when request send and Stop it when request complete/success/failure.

I know that i can use

```
OnBegin = "startLoading",
OnComplete = "stopLoading",
OnFailure = "stopLoading",
OnSuccess = "stopLoading"
```

But, i don't want like this.

I have many request like this.

So, i want make with jQuery.

Once i write jquery script and it will fire for every request.

I do like this :

```
$(document).ajaxSuccess(function () {
  $('#LoadingImage').modal('hide');
});

$(document).ajaxComplete(function () {
    $('#LoadingImage').modal('hide');
});

$(document).ajaxSend(function () {
    $('#LoadingImage').modal('show');
});

$(document).ajaxError(function () {
    $('#LoadingImage').modal('hide');
});
```

But, it working for below syntax only :

```
 $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "NewUser/Testing",
    dataType: "json",
    // cache: false,
    success: function (response) {
        alert("Request Success");  
    },
    error: function (xhr, status) {
        alert('Unknown error ' + status); 
    }
 });
```

And, IT IS NOT WORKING FOR Ajax.BeginForm.

What should i do it works with jquery ?

Any help would be too much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The MVC framework integrates jQuery beautifully. I would recommend that you use jQuery for the form as well. In that case use `Html.BeginForm` instead of `Ajax.BeginForm` something like this :

```
('form').on('submit',function(){
     var form = $(this);
     $.ajax({
        url: form.attr('action'),
        data: form.serialize(),
        dataType: 'json',
        success : function(data){//success function here},
        error : function(resp, status, xhr){}
  });
});
```